# Can a GPS navigation device be tracked?

Tags: gps

Does anyone know if there's a way to track the location of a GPS device knowing its ID? Are there any websites where this information is available?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Does anyone know if there's a way to track the location of a GPS device knowing its ID? Are there any websites where this information is available?*

No, GPS location determination is a problem of precise time measurement (from the beginning of a special week), and sattelite identification. To not go into any details ... it is a one way signal from satelites towards earth, and can not be tracked.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_clock#GPS_clocks

Differentical GPS's are a different matter.

Tracking via GPS navigation (this is a requirement which for example trucking companies have which enables them to locate their vehicles) is a "simple" mechanism of sending out GPS information (NMEA) via an automated SMS messaging service to a centralized location. Very simply put of course, but that is the basic principle.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_tracking
http://www.uktelematicsonline.co.uk/

Comment: What do you mean by "differential GPSs are a different matter"? Differential GPSs are receive-only devices just as are regular GPS receivers. They just receive an additional signal besides the ones from the satellites. So they are no more trackable than regular GPS. It's like trying to "track" any other radio receiver. Unless you are close enough to pick up the device's parasitic EM radiation (CPU clock, local oscillator, etc.) it's not going to be happening, and even then, there's no identifying info that would let you track one particular receiver.

Answer (score 6):

[Time: Why You Can't Track Your Stolen GPS Device](http://www.time.com/time/business/article/0,8599,1735091,00.html)

> It's a cruel irony: Car navigation
>   devices keep you from getting lost,
>   but their location-sensing acumen
>   won't help you find them if they get
>   lost or stolen. Why not? Because
>   location and tracking are two
>   different matters. "The GPS calculates
>   location for you. Communicating that
>   location to a tracking center requires
>   a separate service," says Kanwar
>   Chadha, founder and vice president of
>   SiRF Technology, the largest supplier
>   of GPS chips to navigation device
>   makers.

further...

> Personal navigation units could easily
>   incorporate the same features, but
>   device makers say there's little
>   demand. "Most consumers are just
>   looking to get from Point A to Point
>   B," notes Tom Murray, vice president
>   of TomTom.

Comment: [Nowadays, is there any way to track the movements of my vehicle with GPS precisely?](https://superuser.com/questions/1723070/gps-tracking-precisely)